# How to align the icon relative to the text in RichText?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, richtext

I have a text located in RichText, n how much later I want to make it clickable, there is an icon next to the text. The problem is that the icon does not align correctly relative to the text, this is especially noticeable when its size increases. How do I make the icon and text to be on the same line in the center ? Align centered doesn't help

```
 RichText(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Next ', style: richBotton),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.grey, size: 11,)
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

for styles

```
final richBotton = const  TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117), fontSize: 11,);  
final text = const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 11);
```

[Screen](https://wdfiles.ru/7fd396)

1. My code
2. With  `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.Middle`
3. With `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.Top`
4. With `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.Bottom`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. And maybe some screenshots too.

Comment: Can you include image on stack overflow attachment instead of different domain

Answer (score 0):

You can include `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle` on `WidgetSpan`.

```dart
RichText(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Next ',
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
          child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: 11,
      )),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I tried, but now the icon is shifting up. I tried to wrap the whole RichText in a Row, but that didn't help to align according to your advice either

Comment: Can you include an image what are you trying to archive

Comment: I added an archive with a description to the topic